# Indexed Views And Scalar UDFs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can UDFs be used inside index views or does this break the SCHEMABINDING logic?

For example if in the where clause of the view I had something like this

```
WHERE
     UserCanSeePost(UserId,PostId)
```

This UDF would then do a lookup on another table to check some restrictions. I'm guessing this cant be done in indexed views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if it's [deterministic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) and itself has SCHEMABINDING

See [Indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) too:

> ...
>   User-defined functions referenced in the view must have been created with the SCHEMABINDING option.
>   ...
>   All functions referenced by
>   expressions in the view must be
>   deterministic. The IsDeterministic
>   property of the OBJECTPROPERTY
>   function reports whether a
>   user-defined function is
>   deterministic. For more information,
>   see Deterministic and Nondeterministic
>   Functions.
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

If the function is created WITH SCHEMABINDING, then you can use WITH SCHEMABINDING on a view built on top of it. I'm not 100% sure, but I think functions WITH SCHEMABINDING were introduced in SQL Server 2005...

Edit -> Nope, apparently you could use WITH SCHEMABINDING in 2000 as well.